# Does every thread have its main function?

Tags: threads

Does every thread have its own main function?

I know that its have its own stack, but what about main function (not necessarily a function which called main).

For example, when creating a thread, we pass a function as an argument for the new thread to run it.

I tried to search about this topic, but couldn't find answers.

Comment: Can you define "main function"?

Comment: @harold A function which the thread executes. Just like that the first thread of a program runs the ```main``` method (the "actual" main)

Comment: A thread has an entry point, but whether that qualifies as a "main function" depends on your definition and it is still vague. It's also not clear what you mean by "its own".

Comment: Cross-posted: https://stackoverflow.com/q/63121642/781723, https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/128760/755. Please [do not post the same question on multiple sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64068).

Answer (score 1):

For any reasonable definition of a 'main function', *no*.

Each thread has to start at *some* point in the code. For the main thread that is usually called the main function.

Modern programming languages are often designed that when starting a new thread it starts in a given function. You could call that the 'main function' of that thread, but is more commonly called its entry point.

However the entry point of a thread does not have to be at some dedicated function, or even at the start of a function. As a counterexample I would invite you to look at POSIX `fork()`.

Comment: Isn't ```fork``` used for creating a new process (not a new thread)?

Comment: @Dani A new process implies a new thread. Each process has at least one thread.